# java script in django template: error display with javascript funciton

Tags: javascript, django

Updates:

So right now I changed my code to this:

```
<script>
        function myFunction(calid) {
            document.getElementById(calid).innerHTML = "<ul><li>" + calid + "</li>" + "</ul>";
        }
        </script>

        {% for calibrations in equipment.calibration_set.all %}


        <ul>
            <li>
                <p  onclick="myFunction( {{calibrations.id}} ) ">   {{calibrations.cal_date}}    </p>
                <div id = {{calibrations.id}}> YES </div>


            </li>
        </ul>

        {% endfor %}
```

And it works fine. Thanks!

But then there is one more weird problem: when i tried to add more arguments to the function so that it could display additional information, it just stop working which is really strange since only thing I changed is adding a new arguments. So if I try this:

```
<script>
        function myFunction(calid, calby) {
            document.getElementById(calid).innerHTML = "<ul><li>" + calid + "</li>" + "<li>" + calby + "</li>" + "</ul>";
        }
        </script>

        {% for calibrations in equipment.calibration_set.all %}


        <ul>
            <li>
                <p  onclick="myFunction( {{calibrations.id}}, {{calibrations.cal_by}} ) ">   {{calibrations.cal_date}}    </p>
                <div id = {{calibrations.id}}> YES </div>


            </li>
        </ul>

        {% endfor %}
```

then when i click the date, nothing happens.

1. how come this is wrong?
2. maybe I should use JSON for passing a model data into javascript?

> Old post:
>    I will just dump my code here first:
>
> ```
> {% for calibrations in equipment.calibration_set.all %}
>         <script>
>         function myFunction(cal_id) {
>             document.getElementById(cal_id).innerHTML = "<ul><li>{{calibrations.id}}</li></ul>";
>         }
>         </script>
>         <ul>
>             <li>
>                 <p  onclick="myFunction( {{calibrations.id}} )">{{calibrations.cal_date}}</p>
>                 <div id = {{calibrations.id}}> YES </div>
>
>
>             </li>
>         </ul>
> ```
>
> so calibration is a foreign key of equipment. And here I would like to
>   display a list of calibration associated to a equipment, and using the
>   date of calibration as a javascript onclick event so that a user can
>   click to display the detail information of this calibration. The
>   problem I have is that now even if there are multiple calibrations,
>   clicking the calibration date will change the "Yes" under it to the id
>   of latest calibration.
>
> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> Like in the picture, I clicked the first and second calibration date
>   and expect the text below it to be 1 and 2 respectively.
>
> Could somebody point out what's wrong here?
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFkl.png

Answer (score 3):

You're creating javascript function with same name in every loop. That's why all click are returning same result.

Simple solution is:

```
function myFunction(cal_id) {
    document.getElementById(cal_id).innerHTML = "<ul><li>" + cal_id + "</li></ul>";
}
```

But in general, it's not right to create new function (especially with same name) in every loop.

Comment: Thanks so much! And by the way there is another related new problem that just came out if you happen to have the time to take a look